# Different behaviors of Applicative on tuples and lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, applicative

For example,

```
-- Num a => ([Char], a -> a) <*> ([Char], a)
> ("hello ",(*6)) <*> ("world",7)
("hello world",42)

-- Num a => [a -> a] <*> [a]
> [(*7),(*6)] <*> [6,7]
[42,49,36,42]

-- Num a => [[Char], a -> a] <*> [[Char], a]
> ["hello ",(*6)] <*> ["world",7]
<interactive>:17:2:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char] -> [Char]’
                with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the expression: "hello "
    In the first argument of ‘(<*>)’, namely ‘["hello ", (* 6)]’
    In the expression: ["hello ", (* 6)] <*> ["world", 7]
```

For three examples, `<*>` shows different behaviors. What happens? Why in the third case, it expects a `[Char] -> [Char]` rather than `[Char]` just like in the first case. What's more, even there's only `[Char]` in tuples, `<*>` combines them together.

Comment: [Hoogling "Applicative"](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Applicative) leads to this [`instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)` definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-307) but for lists it's [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-717).

Comment: `[[Char], a -> a]`, or more generally `[a,b]` is not a list in haskell.

Comment: Oh thanks, my stupid. @Franky

Comment: Thanks, that's solves the problem. But it's there any reason that defining list and tuple's Applicative in such ways? Or just a convention. @WillNess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference lies in the fact that lists are *homogeneous*, while tuple are not: lists contain only elements of the same type, while tuples do not have to.

Even without looking at applicatives, functors already show a main difference:

```
fmap succ [1,2,3]  ==> [2,3,4]
fmap succ ("a", 4) ==> ???
```

It would be illogical to argue that `fmap` applies `succ` to `"a"`. What happens is that only the *second* component gets affected:

```
fmap succ ("a", 4) ==> ("a", 5)
```

Indeed, look at the instances:

```
instance Functor [] where ...
instance Functor ((,) a) where ...
```

Notice the `a` type. In the list instance, `[]` takes only one type parameter, and that's the type affected by `fmap`. In `(,)` we have *two* type parameters: one is fixed (to `a`) and does not change when applying `fmap` -- only the second one does.

Note that it would be theoretically possible to admit an instance of `Functor (,)` when both type arguments are forced to be the same. E.g.,

```
instance Functor (\b -> (b,b)) where ...
```

but Haskell does not allow this. If needed, one needs a newtype wrapper:

```
newtype P b = P (b,b)
instance Functor P where
   fmap f (P (x,y)) = P (f x, f y)
```

Answer (score 1):

An Applicative is whatever combination of a datatype and of definitions of `pure` and `<*>` that satisfies the [applicative](https://wiki.haskell.org/Typeclassopedia#Laws_2) [laws](http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/):

```
    [identity] pure id <*> v = v
 [composition] pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
[homomorphism] pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
 [interchange] u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

These laws ensure that `<*>` behaves very much like function application, but one taking place in some kind of "special context" that depends on the Applicative. For the case of `Maybe` the context is the possible absence of value. For tuples, the context is "monoidal annotations that accompany each value".

`pure` and `<*>` can do very different things for different datatypes as long as they respect the laws.

In fact, the *same* datatype can be an Applicative in different ways. Lists have the Applicative instance in which `<*>` "obtains all combinations", but also the instance implemented with the auxiliary [`ZipList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) newtype, where `<*>` zips lists together and `pure` constructs an infinite list.