# How can I use functors or applicatives to rewrite this Haskell function over lists of tuples

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

Is there a nicer way to write the following function `fs'` with functors or applicatives?

```hs
fncnB = (* 2)
fncnA = (* 3)
fs' fs = zip (map (fncnA . fst) fs) $ map (fncnB . snd) fs
```

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852781/different-behaviors-of-applicative-on-tuples-and-lists-in-haskell) that I could rely on the functor instance of lists to map a single function acting over both elements of each tuple, or e.g. on the applicative instance of tuples to apply functions to just the second-half of a two-tuple, but I'm curious how functors and applicatives fit into the picture of operating over lists of multi-component data types.

Comment: Not related to Functor or Applicative, but you could rewrite this nicely with a list comprehension: `fs' fs = [(fncnA x, fncnB y) | (x, y) <- fs]`

Comment: Or, using `Arrow` methods, simply `fs' = map (fncnA &&& fncnB)`. (I think. I'm not really experienced with Arrows.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond: Right idea, wrong function – you want [`(***)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-).  [`(&&&)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) would be for `((* 2) &&& (* 3)) 5 == (10,15)`.

Comment: Thanks @AntalSpector-Zabusky, I knew I'd get mixed up somewhere :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A tuple is a bifunctor, so [`bimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap) is available.

```
import Data.Bifunctor

fncnB = (* 2)
fncnA = (* 3)
fs' = map (bimap fncnA fncnB)
```

No third-party libraries required.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is the mapPair function, it's defined in [the utility-ht package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/utility-ht) but it's just

```
mapPair :: (a -> c, b -> d) -> (a,b) -> (c,d)
mapPair (f,g) (a,b) = (f a, g b)
```

use

```
Prelude> mapPair ((* 2), (* 3)) (2,3)
(4,9)
```

or

```
Prelude> map (mapPair ((* 2), (* 3))) [(1,2),(2,3)]
[(2,6),(4,9)]
```

Comment: `mapPair` is also equal to `uncurry bimap` (where `bimap` is from `Data.Bifunctor`).